# Repushing a branch after deleting it and reforking

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and github, so bear with me.

Here's the scenario:

1. I forked a repo, created a branch named `patch-3`, made some changes, and submitted a pull request to the original owner.
2. A week passes by, and I decide I want to "resync" my old fork, so I delete the old fork, and refork the original project so I can have the most up-to-date version.
3. The old pull request is still open, and the original owner replies back saying he wants to merge my changes, but `patch-3` has disappeared. He then asked me if I can "repush" it.
4. I go back to my new fork, and create a new branch called `patch-3` and reapply my initial changes. That's it.

My question is: will the old pull request now pick up the new `patch-3` branch I created in the new fork, so the original owner can merge my changes? I did not see any indication of what I did in the old pull request page... so something seems to be off here.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to make a new pull request.

The right way, in order to get the most up-to-date version *and* still have your pull request, is:

- to fetch upstream (the original repo)
- rebase `patch-3` on top of it
- push it to your fork (named 'origin')

... and you will see the pull request automagically updated with the new SHA1 of your branch.

See "[Git fork is git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)" for the difference between the remote upstream and origin.

[image: upstream and fork]

The point is: don't delete/recreate repos: you can update and rebase.

See also "[My pull request has been merged, what to do next?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772000/6309)".

For more tips; see "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".