# Git: New pull request from the same branch still shows previous commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a repo on github, then I did `git checkout X` and made some changes to branch `X`. After finishing up,  I made a pull request from branch `X` of the forked repo to branch `X` of the original repo. 
My changes got merged with branch `X` of the original repo, then I made some more changes and made another pull request from my branch `X` to original repo's branch `X`. However, this still shows my previously merged commits as under,
[image]

Here, commits made till `Jul 05, 2017` have already been merged to branch `X` of the original repo. I only need the commits on `Jul 06` to show up on this pull request. After trying for quite some time I'm unable to find a solution. Here's what I did based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770550/my-pull-request-has-been-merged-what-to-do-next) post,

setup new upstream like so - 
`git remote add upstream https://path/to/original/repo.git`

fetch changes to update my forked repo - `git fetch upstream`

rebase onto branch X - `git rebase X`

However, now I see an even bigger list of commits staged for the pull request. I'm sure I don't fully understand how pull requests work but I'm assuming this is because my forked repo does not know that previous commits have already been merged. 
I know the usual workflow should be to fork the repo, make a new branch for every change, make a pull request, delete the branch once changes have been merged. I wasn't aware of that and stumbled on this problem. How do I only include the newly (un-merged) commits in the pull request, and not all the previous ones as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits from a fresh new branch from upstream:

```
git fetch upstream X:X_new
git checkout X_new
git cherry-pick 92495c5
git cherry-pick ...
```

You can then open a new pull request. If you want to keep the same pull-request, you will need to rename it to the old name, and force push to your repo:

```
git checkout X
git checkout -b X_backup
git branch -D X
git checkout X_new
git checkout -b X
git push origin X -f
```

and then if it fits your need, you can delete the other branches:

```
git branch -D X_backup
git branch -D X_new
```